# Bash script - Mysql replace

Tags: mysql

I want replace only "Youtube link columns to "uniq_id.mp4"

it should be a similar code:

```
mysql -u user -p pass -Ddatabase -e "UPDATE pm_videos SET url_flv='$uniq_id.mp4' WHERE url_flv='%youtube%'";
```

Table name: pm_videos

```
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
| id | uniq_id    | url_flv                                   |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 994618688  |http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndigRRv6L-Y |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
|  2 | 926266406  |926266406.mp4                              |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
|  3 | 783849566  |783849566.mp4                              |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
|  4 | 627382734  |http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhW1f6enMb0 |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

I need this replace:

```
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
| id | uniq_id    | url_flv                                   |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 994618688  |994618688.mp4                              |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
|  2 | 926266406  |926266406.mp4                              |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
|  3 | 783849566  |783849566.mp4                              |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
|  4 | 627382734  |627382734.mp4                              |
+----+------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This has little to do with `shell` or `bash`.  You need a sql here which seems trivial enough.

Answer (score 0):

Update your table,

```
update pm_videos set url_flv= CONCAT(uniq_id,'.mp4')
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is proper SQL.

In your example:

```
UPDATE pm_videos SET url_flv='$uniq_id.mp4' WHERE url_flv='%youtube%'
```

you compare (`=`) `url_flv` to `'%youtube%'` while I guess you want to use `LIKE` here instead. Please note that if you have many rows in this table, then `%` on both sides can slow down your query.

Second thing is that you try to use some strange thing in SQL which is `$uniq_id` ( I guess you tried some variable?). You should use a column name and concatenate it with `.mp4` string.

Try:

```
UPDATE pm_videos SET url_flv=CONCAT(uniq_id,'.mp4') WHERE url_flv LIKE '%youtube%'
```